# Sublime Text 2 how to wrap selection with quotes/auto-pairing

Tags: autocomplete, editor, textmate, text-editor, sublimetext2

I just switched from Textmate 2 to Sublime Text 2. I figured that typing single quotes or brackets would automatically generate a second quote or bracket with the cursor in between ("auto-pairing" is what they call it, Textmate2 does this by default) but this isn't happening.

I see that in the `preferences->settings-Default` there is some JSON configuration that would seem to be doing what I need but this is not the case. I haven't changed any of this default configuration.

Could someone help me add to my `preferences->settings-User` the configuration I need to enable auto-pairing for all the common tags, i.e., `"'{[(`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now I'm working on a client's laptop and running Sublime Text 2 portable version from my flash drive. No additional packages installed, default settings. Everything works as expected:

1. When I type a single or double quote, brackets, square or curly brackets it adds a closing one and puts cursor in the middle.
2. When I select smth and press any of mentioned above keys it surrounds selection with pair of appropriate quotes or brackets.

Check your Settings>Default, look for this:

```
// Controls auto pairing of quotes, brackets etc
"auto_match_enabled": true,
```

It's near line 89 or so.

Comment: -@Ihor, thanks you were right, i must have set `"auto_match_enabled"` to `false` at some point. Can you help with the other problem which is when you type a single quote `"`, it automatically generates the second quote `"` and puts the cursor in between the two?

Comment: Sure, I can try. Can you explain in details? Because I don't understand the problem from your comment.

Comment: Ok, i'd like to type a single quote `"` and have Sublime produce two quotes with the cursor in between like this: `"|"` (the pipe is the cursor).

Comment: never mind, i stopped and re-started ST2 and now it works as i want. I'm not sure if the problem was fixed by changing auto_matched_enabled to true or by adding sublimeCodeIntel plugins, but it works so yeah, thanks for your help!

Comment: It works like this by default, I bet it worked after restart. Anyway, CodeIntel is good package. Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't work in ST3, even with a clean portable version.  Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, I have to do the opening bracket, not the closing like I expected. Anyway that can be reversed?

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer to your question..but I have installed a few plugins in ST2 and auto-pairing works fine.

I am not sure which plugin is responsible for it. Let me know if you would like me to share the list of plugins.

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/0t0y3p3U063z

http://cl.ly/image/0o3k0X3y401O

http://cl.ly/image/3c3U0f1I3s12

http://cl.ly/image/1O2p0r2i0m0W

http://drp.so/f713e9ae8e301755f30c19516092430a

Comment: -@Sridhar, thanks! it looks like @Ihor has the first problem solved, would you mind looking at my comment to his answer on automatically generating both quotes?

Comment: When I type

`<a href="`

immediately the ending double quote gets automatically inserted and the cursor placed in between the two quotes.

Did you get a chance to see the plugins I have in place and try them out? Perhaps it is SublimeCodeIntel that does this?

Comment: -@Sridhar I installed SublimeCodeintel but that didn't solve the problem. The other programs didn't look right either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: never mind, i stopped and re-started ST2 and now it works as i want. I'm not sure if the problem was fixed by changing auto_matched_enabled to true or by adding sublimeCodeIntel plugins, but it works so yeah, thanks for your help!